# stl vector size on 64-bit machines

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have an application that will use millions of vectors.

It appears that most implementations of std::vector use 4 pointers (_First, _Last, _End, and _Alloc), which consumes 32 bytes on 64-bit machines.  For most "practical" use cases of vector, one could probably get away with a single pointer and two 'unsigned int' fields to store the current size & allocated size, respectively.  Ignoring the potential challenge of supporting customized allocation (instead of assuming that allocations must go through the global new & delete operator), it seems that it is possible to build an STL compliant vector class that uses only 16 bytes (or at worst 24 bytes to support the _Alloc pointer).

Before I start coding this up, 1) are there any pitfalls I should be aware of and 2) does an open source implementation exist?

Comment: Are the vectors related to each other? Like, are they rows in matrices? If so, you can apply other optimizations that don't require you to reimplement `std::vector`.

Comment: sounds like premature optimization to me.  Write the application logic and then, if the size of the vector overhead is an issue look, into a solution.

Comment: Chances are that you can think over your profile of memory usage and try to arrange it more efficiently than a million of vectors. Do all of them need to grow independently? Is it impossible to predict their size?

Comment: *"I have an application that will use millions of vectors"* - wow, and you really need completely dynamic resizing for each of those independently? Sounds like a good starting point for a datastructure redesign. This may not only reduce the overall size but also increase performance, when using more localized data than a completely different memory area for each small bunch of numbers (or whatever's in there), though I don't know your underlying problem and maybe you really need millions of `std::vector`s.

Comment: On my 64-bit box, `sizeof(std::vector<int>)` is 24, I would do as @AnonMail says...

Comment: @Nim: What platform/compiler is that?

Comment: @BillyONeal (`gcc version 4.6.1 20110701 [gcc-4_6-branch revision 175746] (SUSE Linux)` with `-m64`)

Comment: @Nim: Interesting. I was not aware that they had implemented the optimization to remove the `Alloc` member for the default allocator in libstdc++.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: `capacity()` if used in that sense would be a `size_t`, which is the same width as a pointer. (So even if it's not a pointer, size wise it is the same as a pointer) `_Last` would be the same thing as storing `capacity()` (that is, `_Last` is `begin()+capacity()`) The 4th pointer is to the allocator.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Oh, right I missed the allocator. In many cases libraries optimize the allocator pointer away (for example, the default allocator is fully stateless, so there is no need to maintain it)

Answer (score 5):

You could accomplish something like this -- but it's not likely you'd gain all that much.

First, there's the performance aspect. You are trading time for memory consumption. Whatever memory you save is going to be offset by having to do the addition and a multiply on every call to `end` (okay, if it's a vector where `sizeof(vector<t>::value_type) == 1` the multiply can be optimized out). Note that most handwritten looping code over vectors calls `end` on every loop iteration. On modern CPUs that's actually going to be a major win, because it allows the processor to keep more things in cache; unless those couple of extra instructions in an inner loop force the processor to swap things in the instruction cache too often)

Moreover, the memory savings is likely to be small in terms of the overall memory use in the vector, for the following reasons:

- Memory manager overhead. Each allocation from the memory manager, (which vector of course needs) is going to add 16-24 bytes of overhead on its own in most memory manager implementations. (Assuming something like `dlmalloc` (UNIX/Linux/etc.) or `RtlHeap` (Windows))
- Overprovisioning load. In order to achieve amortized constant insertion and removal at the end, when vector resizes, it resizes to some multiple of the size of the data in the vector. This means that the typical memory capacity vector allocates is enough for 1.6 (MSVC++) or 2 (STLPort, libstdc++) times the number of elements actually stored in the vector.
- Alignment restrictions. If you are putting those many vectors into an array (or another vector), then keep in mind the first member of that vector is still a pointer to the allocated memory block. This pointer generally needs to be 8 byte aligned anyway -- so the 4 bytes you save are lost to structure padding in arrays.

I'd use the plain implementation of vector for now. If you run your code through a memory profiler and find that a significant savings would be made by getting rid of these couple of pointers, then you're probably off implementing your own optimized class which meets your performance characteristics rather than relying on the built in vector implementation. (An example of one such optimized class is `std::string` on those platforms that implement the small string optimization)

(Note: the only compiler of which I am aware that optimizes out the `Alloc` pointer is VC11, which isn't yet released. Though Nim says that the current prerelease version of libstdc++ does it as well...)

Answer (score 1):

Unless these vectors are going to have contents that are extremely small, the difference between 16 vs. 32 bytes to hold the contents will be a small percentage of the total memory consumed by them. It will require lots of effort to reinvent this wheel, so be sure you're getting an adequate pay off for all that work.

BTW, there's value in education too, and you will learn a lot by doing this. If you choose to proceed, you might consider writing a test suite first, and exercise it on the current implementation and then on the one you invent.

Answer (score 0):

To answer if it is worth the effort, find or write a compatible implementation that fits *your* needs (maybe there are other things in std::vector that you do not need), and compare the performance with `std::vector<your_type>` on relevant platforms. Your suggestion can at least improve performance of for the move constructor, as well as the move assignment operator:

```
typedef int32_t v4si __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
union
    {
    v4si data;
    struct
        {
        T* pointer;
        uint32_t length;
        uint32_t capacity;
        } content;
    } m_data;
```

This only covers "sane" `T` (noexcept move semantices). https://godbolt.org/g/d5yU3o